# CSS Menu Animation with Icons

Tags: html, css, animation, navigation, zurb-foundation

Good Morning everyone. I have a small project where I would like to do in CSS without JavaScript if possible.

Is it possible to create element where on hover of the parent element, a image will load in next to text?

Ive added a Jsfiddle so you can hopefully see what i mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/atx9re4s/

on hover the text slides to the right, i would like to see if its possible to have a image load into that space left of the text. i have used a image tag for this but is it possible using a cdn font like ico moon as well that will change the tag to a span with a class.

Thank you for the help.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div>
    <div class="button">
        <img src="http://www.midnightbsd.org/art/logo/MidnightBSDLogo64x64.png">         
        Reserve your Spot
    </div>
</div>

<!-- CSS -->
/* the button */
.button {
    background: #f0aa28;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: .3s;
}
.button:hover {
    background: #0e4fad; 
    padding-left: 60px;
}

/* the icon */
.button img {display: none;}
.button img < .button:hover {display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: Could you put your code on jsfiddle ?

Comment: Explain more what you want, what is the problem, it's really unclear

Comment: added the jsfiddle link and cleaned up the code so its much simpler to see what i am trying to achieve. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/p7o75pLv/

The trick is to set the image as a background image for the div on hover, like so:

```
.button:hover {
    background: #0e4fad; 
    background-image: url("http://www.midnightbsd.org/art/logo/MidnightBSDLogo64x64.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i wanted. appreciate the help ^^